# How can I remove duplicate elements in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I trying to write a program that will output information to me in the form of a JSON file, but I ran into the fact that I duplicate information with the `"exchange_id"` parameter, but with other info. I want information with this value to be displayed to me once. How can I do this?

Example of JSON file:

```
{
            "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
            "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/eth_btc",
            "price": 48637.97781883441,
            "last_update": "2021-12-09T17:11:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 102
        },
{
            "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
            "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/xrp_btc",
            "price": 48656.10607332287,
            "last_update": "2021-12-09T17:10:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 102
        },
```

My code:

```
json_data = response['data']
            pairs = []
            out_object = {}

            exchangeIds = {102,311,200,302,521,433,482,406,42,400}

            for pair in json_data["marketPairs"]:
                if pair['exchangeId'] in set(exchangeIds):
                    pairs.append({

                        "exchange_name": pair["exchangeName"],
                        "market_url": pair["marketUrl"],
                        "price": pair["price"],
                        "last_update" : pair["lastUpdated"],
                        "exchange_id": pair["exchangeId"]

                        })

                    out_object["name_of_coin"] = json_data["name"]
                    out_object["marketPairs"] = pairs
                    out_object["pairs"] = json_data["numMarketPairs"]
 
                    name = json_data["name"]

                    save_path = '.\swapMarketCap\coins'
                    file_name = f'{name}'
                    path_to_coin = os.path.join(save_path, file_name +".json")
```

Comment: You can remove the element from exchangeIds after you create its json entry. After creating the json entry for exchangeIds  = 102 just remove 102 from the set.

Comment: What would be in this example the desired output?

Comment: I would to be only one thing of output, like this:

Comment: "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
            "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/eth_btc",
            "price": 48637.97781883441,
            "last_update": "2021-12-09T17:11:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 102

Comment: In your JSON fragment we see two  elements each with the same exchange_id. Are you saying that you would want to keep the first one but ignore the second even though the other values (e.g., last_update) are different. Or, are you saying that you only want a single occurrence of an exchange_id that's defined in your constant set? It would also help if you could show more relevant data - specifically, the dictionary that *response* refers to

Comment: Yes, a need to keep first and ignore the second

Comment: How is you get exchangeId but in a sample json it is of the format as such exchange_id?

Comment: Is the meaning to say that they (the fields) are camel cased in a sample file of json? e.g. excName and not exc_name.

Comment: I'm taking exchangeId by API:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/market-pairs/latest?slug=infinitup&start=1&limit=100&category=spot&sort=cmc_rank_advanced

Comment: @PPPGPPPG so just to clarify , what exactly are you trying to do here? is the goal just to filter out market places that match a specific `id`, and also to ensure that only the first market with the `id` is captured? based on the above, it looks like the other implicit goal is to ensure only certain fields are saved in the output JSON, and some fields are implicitly mapped to a new name - for ex. in the API response I see a `lastUpdated` field, but in the output json you have a `last_update`. Also lots of other fields like `depthUsdNegativeTwo` seem to be missing in the output JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of more detail, here's a pattern that you could use. This does **not** purport to be rewrite of your code and also makes certain assumptions (in the absence of detail in the original question). However, it should help you:

```
response = {'data':
            {'marketPairs': [{
                "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
                "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/eth_btc",
                "price": 48637.97781883441,
                "last_update": "2021-12-09T17:11:53.000Z",
                "exchange_id": 102
            },
                {
                "exchange_name": "Huobi Global",
                "market_url": "https://www.huobi.com/en-us/exchange/xrp_btc",
                "price": 48656.10607332287,
                "last_update": "2021-12-09T17:10:53.000Z",
                "exchange_id": 102
            }
            ]}}

exchangeIds = {102, 311, 200, 302, 521, 433, 482, 406, 42, 400}

output = {'data': {'marketPairs': []}}

for d in response['data']['marketPairs']:
    if (id := d.get('exchange_id', None)):
        if id in exchangeIds:
            output['data']['marketPairs'].append(d)
            exchangeIds.remove(id)

print(output)
```

So, the underlying idea is that you have a set of IDs that you're interested in. Once you find one that's in the set, take the reference to the current dictionary and add it to the new dictionary (*output*). Then, crucially, remove the previously processed ID from the set.